# graphql fails at adiing 100+ products to my Wordpress Woocomerce store

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, woocommerce, graphql, gatsby

Anyone knows how to fix this graphql error? I couldn't add more than 50 items to my store. 
I have raised the timeout in options schema `options: {schema: { timeout: 1000000,},}` 
and added this line to wp.config file `define( ‘WP_MEMORY_LIMIT’, ‘512M’ );`
 but it didn't solve the problem. My maximum's 46 items, but I guess that's not the limit.

```
info  gatsby-source-wordpress  GraphQL vars: {"first":70,"url":"http://my-web-url/graphql","after":null}
error  gatsby-source-wordpress  Your wordpress server at http://my-web-url/graphql appears to be overloaded.
Try reducing the requestConcurrency for content updates or the previewRequestConcurrency for previews:
{
  resolve: 'gatsby-source-wordpress-experimental',
  options: {
    schema: {
      requestConcurrency: 5, // currently set to undefined
      previewRequestConcurrency: 2, // currently set to undefined
    }
  },
}
The GATSBY_CONCURRENT_REQUEST environment variable is no longer used to control concurrency.
If you were previously using that, you'll need to use the settings above instead.
not finished source and transform nodes - 5.466s
not finished  gatsby-source-wordpress  fetching nodes - 5.390s - 15 total
not finished  gatsby-source-wordpress  PaColor - 3.871s
not finished Downloading remote files - 3.569s
not finished Generating image thumbnails - 3.428s
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: /node14/bin/node
Arguments: /vercel/.yarn/lib/cli.js build
Directory: /vercel/path0/site
Output:
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/workspace for documentation about this command.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! gatsby-woocommerce-themes@2.0.1 build: `yarn workspace site build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the gatsby-woocommerce-themes@2.0.1 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /vercel/.npm/_logs/2021-09-21T17_39_01_248Z-debug.log
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's quite straightforward. You've reached a timeout/overloading response, not only because of the number of pages but its content and heaviness. Use the provided solution:

```
{
  resolve: 'gatsby-source-wordpress',
  options: {
    schema: {
      requestConcurrency: 50, 
      previewRequestConcurrency: 50, 
    }
  },
}
```

And play with [`requestConcurrency`](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby-source-wordpress/docs/plugin-options.md#schemarequestconcurrency) and [`previewRequestConcurrency`](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby-source-wordpress/docs/plugin-options.md#schemapreviewrequestconcurrency) values as the docs suggests. Using the previous values (50) should work because now are set as `undefined` so you should see some improvements.

Notice the following statement which is also important if you are using `GATSBY_CONCURRENT_REQUEST` environment variable:

> The `GATSBY_CONCURRENT_REQUEST` environment variable is no longer used
> to control concurrency. If you were previously using that, you'll need
> to use the settings above instead.